# One domain and multiple mail servers

Tags: email-server

I would like two email servers with one domain.

How to handle it? Is it possible to do this in easy way?

I'll describe what I would like to achieve.

I have a domain called **domain.com**
I have a normal mail server, my own, called **MAIL1**, which can receive and send email (I use poste.io as mail server). This mail server use for standard mails like contact@domain.com, info@domain.com etc.
This mail server is configured to use A (mail.domain.com) and MX record (MX shows on "mail.domain.com" value).

For now, I would like to create a second mail server (called **MAIL2**) on a different host and IP address. This mail server I would like to use as server for clients like client1@domain.com, client2@domain.com.

**How to configure this case?**

The perfect solution is possible to receive and send emails from both servers, but good enough for me is to receive and send email from **MAIL1** and only receive email on **MAIL2** (I will not send emails from **MAIL2**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what mail server software do you use. You have to configure the MTA on your **MAIL1** server so that it forwards messages for selected recipients to **MAIL2** server. It also depends on how many these addresses you have. If you have only a few, you can eg. set up an alias for any of these addresses that just redirects mail to **MAIL2**. For a large number of addresses, you need to set up some general rules and maybe use custom transports (this is how Postfix calls it; other MTAs may use completely different language). Usually there are multiple methods of achieving that, each of them has its pros and cons. It's best to ask on a forum/mailing list that is dedicated to the particular MTA software you are using - and doing this, provide more details on your configuration etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answer.